# Qt5.2 NetworkManager::networkInterfaces()

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5

i am trying to compile a simple Qt5.2 program wich uses libnm-qt5 & libmm-qt5 to manage connections, but when i am trying to list them with this code:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <QtCore/QTextStream>

#include <NetworkManagerQt5/manager.h>
#include <NetworkManagerQt5/device.h>
#include <NetworkManagerQt5/activeconnection.h>
#include <NetworkManagerQt5/connection.h>

QString typeAsString(const int type)
{
    switch (type) {
    case 0x0: return QString("Unknown");
    case 0x1: return QString("Ethernet");
    case 0x2: return QString("Wifi");
    case 0x3: return QString("Unused1");
    case 0x4: return QString("Unused2");
    case 0x5: return QString("Bluetooth");
    case 0x6: return QString("OlpcMesh");
    case 0x7: return QString("Wimax");
    case 0x8: return QString("Modem");
    }
    return QString("Unknown");
}

int main()
{
    QTextStream qout(stdout, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

    NetworkManager::Device::List list = NetworkManager::networkInterfaces();

    foreach (NetworkManager::Device *dev, list) {
        qout << dev->uni() << "\n";
```

i am getting an error in QtCreator: "/home/me/Qt/5.2.1/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:860: error: cannot convert 'const QSharedPointer' to 'NetworkManager::Device*' in initialization
     for (variable = **container*.i;; **extension** ({--*container*.brk; break;}))
                                  ^"

I've been searching in some repositories like tis: https://build.merproject.org/package/view_file?file=enable-contour.patch&package=plasma-mobile&project=home%3Awonko%3Apa-devel-contour-hack&rev=21 and they use:

```
NetworkManager::Device::List iflist = NetworkManager::networkInterfaces();
    foreach (NetworkManager::Device::Ptr iface, iflist){

}
```

but it gives me error too. Does anyone know the correct solution?

Thanks.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. I cannot reproduce the issue. Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Now is compiling, but it throws: *** Error in `/home/mine/qt5/build-consola-red-Desktop_Qt_5_2_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/consola-red': malloc(): memory corruption: 0x000000000194b330 *** I am running this: https://projects.kde.org/projects/extragear/libs/libnm-qt/repository/revisions/master/entry/examples/createconnection/main.cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
foreach (NetworkManager::Device *dev, list) { ...
```

with this:

```
foreach (NetworkManager::Device::ptr dev, list) { ...
```